# How to get column value or null from inner join in case other column is true or false

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I'm joining using an `INNER JOIN`; one has the same 3 security names and the other are registers for case users of codes and primary columns.

```
Select S.SecurityName, SC.SecurityCode 
from Securities S 
   INNER JOIN SecurityCodes SC ON S.SecurityId = SC.SecurityId 
WHERE SC.UserId = 1
```

```
SecurityName  SecurityCode    Primary    UserId
----------------------------------------------
C             10              1          1
I             20              0          1
S             30              1          1
```

I need to get the security names and security codes that has Primary true, but in case that Primary is false (so there is no primary security code), the query must return Security Name normally and SecurityCode as null.

Expected:

```
SecurityName SecurityCode
--------------------------
I            NULL
C            10
S            30
```

NOTE: The security name can't be repeated, that's why if there is not a primary security code, it shows null.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: You've indicated the problem involves a join, but you've only shown one of the tables involved.  It doesn't seem clear why the expected result doesn't include a row where SecurityName = 'S'?

Comment: A table does not have "registers", it has columns

Answer (score 2):

Looks you have not added entire query(inner join) that you mentioned. But you need to use `case` statement.

```
SELECT SecurityName, 
CASE WHEN PRIMARY='1' THEN SecurityCode ELSE NULL END AS SECURITY_CODE
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: The problem is this script returns repeated security names. It should be a priority of the cases that has primary true

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3523/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (SecurityName varchar(20),SecurityCode int,Prim bit)
INSERT INTO MyTable(SecurityName,SecurityCode,Prim) VALUES ('C',10,1),('I',20,0),('S',30,1)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SecurityName,IIF(Prim=0, NULL, Prim) AS SecurityCode
FROM MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3523/2/0)**:

```
| SecurityName | SecurityCode |
|--------------|--------------|
|            C |         true |
|            I |       (null) |
|            S |         true |
```

Comment: This could work the problem is if exists a ('C',20,0) it must return the one with primary true, and if there's no one with primary just return null

Comment: @MattDmc please try to explain more your issue with a concrete example.Your question is closed due to lack of information.